# Integral computation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I need to compute (for $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{R^+}$)
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda \mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y }x\mathbb{1}_{x \geq y} dxdy$$
The integrand is clearly Lebesgue-integrable, so we can apply Fubini's theorem.

Integrating first over $y$, then over $x$ we get 
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} \lambda \mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y }x dydx= \int_{0}^{\infty}  \lambda xe^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\mu x}) dx=\frac{1}{\mu}+\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{1}{\lambda + \mu}$ with integration by parts. This part is correct.

Then I tried to integrate over $x$ first. Since we are integrating over the first quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $y \leq x$, we shall let $y$ go from $0$ to $\infty$, then for a fixed $y$, $x$ goes from $y$ to $\infty$. So the integral becomes:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda \mu e^{-\mu y } \int_{y}^{\infty}  e^{-\lambda x}x dxdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda \mu e^{-\mu y } (\frac{1}{\lambda}ye^{-\lambda y}+ \frac{1}{\lambda^2}e^{-\lambda y})dy
=\mu ( \int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-(\lambda+\mu)y}dy+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-(\lambda+\mu)y}dy )=\frac{\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}-\frac{\mu}{\lambda(\lambda+\mu)^2}$

So the 2 integrals don't coincide. I'd be very thankful if someone points out what I did wrong in the second computation. Also if anyone knows any software to compute this kind of integrals with parameters I'd be very interested

Comment: Ignore my comments, missed the single $x$ added to the product.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the evaluation of the very last integral is wrong, there should be no square in the very last term. Not that this makes things better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, integrating by $y$ first is easier.

You've miscomputed the outer integral.

Note that, for $\alpha>0$: $$f(\alpha):=\int_0^\infty xe^{-\alpha x}x=\frac1{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}\,dx  =\frac1{\alpha^2}\tag2$$

Your outer integral then should be:
$$\begin{align} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda x e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\mu x})\,dx&=\lambda\left(f(\lambda)-f(\lambda+\mu)\right)\\&=\frac1\lambda -\frac\lambda{(\lambda+\mu)^2}\\
&=\frac{\mu(2\lambda+\mu)}{\lambda(\lambda+\mu)^2}
\end{align}$$

This is the same as:

$$\frac{\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}+\frac\mu{\lambda(\lambda+\mu)}$$ which is what you should have gotten in the last step when integrating by $x$ first.

Your error there is the second term:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\lambda+\mu)y}\,dy=\frac1{\lambda+\mu},$$ not $-\frac1{(\lambda+\mu)^2}.$

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the result of he second approach is $\frac{\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}+\frac{\mu}{\lambda(\lambda+\mu)}$,  so the results coincide.

Comment: @Matija OP has $(\lambda+\mu)^2$ in both denominators, though.

Comment: And a leading $-$ for the second fraction. That's why I wanted to point out this miscalculation, too, to justify Fubini using the famous proof by example :-)

Comment: +1. Sorry for the late feedback. I corrected as you suggested the calculations of the integral over x first and got the same result as you as the sum of 2 terms. Still this results seems to be different than the one I got by integrating over y first. Can you explain why?

Comment: My answer show why **both** your computations were wrong.